# How should I decompose a flex application in views?

Tags: apache-flex, modularity

What are the criteria for decomposing a Flex applicaiton to views?
I find quite difficult to apply the Single Responsibility Principle in this context.
I've come to the following conclusions through my experience:

*More monolithic approach*(e.g. one view per tab, lots of panels in the same tab)

- Very easy communication between components as only one Presentation Model is used
- Cannot use multiple States, only on the top level component.

*More modular approach* (e.g. one view per panel)

(the opposite to the monolithic one)

Answer (score 0):

Expose public properties on the child views, and then listen to the child views for events that announce that the user has interacted with the Views.